# Python combinations of elements in dict

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have a bunch of dicts like the one below (some can be quite large):

```
V = {
    0: [823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036],
    823: [832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551],
    832: [1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551],
    1151: [1752, 2548, 3036, 3551],
    1752: [2548, 3036, 3551, 4622],
    2548: [3036, 3551, 4622],
    3036: [3551, 4622, 5936, 6440],
    3551: [4622, 5936, 6440],
    4622: [5936, 6440, 9001],
    5936: [6440, 9001],
    6440: [9001],
    9001: []
}
```

**The dict represents basic rules to help derive all possible paths (they are routes). A path is a sequence of the above ints.**

Every value in the list of dict values is also a key.

How do I determine all possible paths knowing that for example:

[3036, 4622, 9001] is a valid path,

But [3036, 9001] is not, and the reason, is that 3036 must be followed by one of the elements in V[3036]. And every combination must contain a compatible sequence, and every sequence must end with 9001, which says, that to get to 9001, one must go via 6440, or 5936 or 4622.

Every sequence must also start with one the points in V[0].

Two things I tried:

1. I first used itertools.product to derive all paths and then filter out invalid ones, but for most dicts, the number of itertools.product combinations is just too large.
2. Monte Carlo sims but the number of loops is in the millions with no guarantee to capture all paths.

Comment: "How do I determine all combinations": out of what? Out of all numbers? Out of the numbers posted in the question?

Comment: What is a "combination" for you? What does the dict represent? What does a given combination represent? Making a **complete wild guess**, is it that the dict represents a directed acyclic graph structure by mapping nodes to their successors, and you want to find all paths from the root to a leaf? Could you show a smaller example input - small enough to work out the correct answer by hand, but big enough to illustrate the complications - and the *exact, complete* answer for that input?

Comment: That said: if your problem specification says "all possibilities" (or anything like that, which indicates an "exhaustive search", *immediately rule out* Monte Carlo sims as having any possible use. Monte Carlo is *by definition* intended for random sampling of a large possibility space, so that you can get roughly accurate *statistics or probabilities*.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, we can assume that the integers in each value list a) are all valid keys; b) are strictly greater than the corresponding key; c) are sorted in ascending order?

Comment: @Karl. Yes all ints are valid keys, and and are strictly greater than the corresponding dict key.

Comment: Is the empty list for 9001 the only one, or can there be others?

Comment: How large is "quite large"?

Comment: @Kelly. 9001 represents the route destination and only the destination can show an empty list.

Comment: What are you going to do with all the routes? Maybe producing+handling them all individually is not the best way. Like in the extreme case of only wanting to know how many there are.

Comment: @Kelly. I need them all to run through a fitness function.

Comment: Sounds even more like you'd better not do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a simple DFS.  Since the graph appears to be directed (each node has successors whose numbers are greater than that of the node), you don't even need to be careful to avoid cycles.

```
>>> def dfs(graph, start, end):
...     if start == end:
...         return [[end]]
...     return [[start] + result for s in graph[start] for result in dfs(graph, s, end)]
...
>>> dfs(V, 0, 9001)
[[0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 4622, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 4622, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 4622, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 4622, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3551, 4622, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3551, 4622, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3551, 4622, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3551, 4622, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3551, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3551, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3551, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 4622, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 4622, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 4622, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 4622, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 3551, 4622, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 3551, 4622, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 3551, 4622, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 3551, 4622, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 3551, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 3551, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 3551, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 4622, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 4622, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 4622, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 4622, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3036, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3551, 4622, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3551, 4622, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3551, 4622, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3551, 4622, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3551, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3551, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 3551, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 4622, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 4622, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 4622, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 4622, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 3551, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 3551, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 3551, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 4622, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 4622, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 4622, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 4622, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3036, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3551, 4622, 5936, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 2548, 3551, 4622, 5936, 9001], ...]
```

If the above function spins forever on one of your dicts, then it's time to revise the assumption about the graph being directed.

Comment: Thank you Samwise. It indeed spins forever on a few of my graphs. Very elegant solution. Also thanks for the pointer re revising the assumption about the graph. I am now building a fitness function prior to feeding the graph to the recursive function. Bonus is that it's very easy to implement in another language.

Comment: @hcb Does it spin "forever" because of cycles or because the number of paths is just very big?

Comment: (It can't truly run "forever", without cycles it'll either finish or crash due to limited memory, and   *with* cycles it'll get a recursion limi error).

Comment: Runs "forever" may hit memory limit, because of the number of waypoints. Graphs show no cycles.

Comment: @hcb So even more reason to not go through them all individually. Depending on the bigger picture, it could still be possible to do in a split second, but we'd have to know that bigger picture (maybe ask another question with that).

Answer (score 2):

You can treat the dictionary as an adjacency list. You could use vanilla Python (as in Samwise's answer), but their answer won't work if the graph has cycles.

`networkx` exposes a method for finding the desired paths, so we can use that. This function returns a generator, meaning that it doesn't load all of the paths into memory at once (although you can if you want to using `list()` -- but you might run out of memory if the graph is large):

```py
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.DiGraph(V)
for path in nx.all_simple_paths(graph, 0, 9001):
    print(path)
```

The first and last three lines of the output:

```py
[0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 5936, 6440, 9001]
[0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 5936, 9001]
[0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 6440, 9001]
... [755 more lines]
[0, 3036, 5936, 6440, 9001]
[0, 3036, 5936, 9001]
[0, 3036, 6440, 9001]
```

Comment: Thank you! Great package. This works and runs quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

Non-Recursive Depth First Search Generator Function

- solution faster than the other two solutions (i.e. networkx, dfs)
- updated with an observation by KellyBundy in comments which made code slightly faster.

**Code**

```
def dfs_stack(graph, start, goal):
    '''
        Depth First Search for all paths from start to goal
    '''
    # Init stack to path with just starting vertex
    stack = [[start]]
    
    while stack:
        # Expand path at end of stack
        path = stack.pop()
        
        if path[-1] == goal:
            yield path                # reached goal
        else:
            # Add all paths of vertex to stack
            for start in graph[path[-1]]:
                stack.append(path + [start])
```

**Usage**

```
# Use list on generator to obtain all paths
paths = list(dfs_stack(V, 0, 9001))

print(paths [:3])    # First 3 paths
# Output: [0, 3036, 6440, 9001], [0, 3036, 5936, 9001], [0, 3036, 5936, 6440, 9001]]

print(paths [-3:])    # Last 3 paths
# Output: [[0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 6440, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 5936, 9001], [0, 823, 832, 1151, 1752, 2548, 3036, 3551, 4622, 5936, 6440, 9001]]
```

**Timing Comparison**

The current approach is over twice as fast as the other two posted solutions on the OP data.

```
Current Approach
    %timeit list(dfs_stack(V, 0, 9001))
    Result: 874 µs ± 42.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

DFS function from Samwise solution
    %timeit dfs(V, 0, 9001)
    Result: 2.1 ms ± 91.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Networkx solution from BrokenBenchmark solution
    %%timeit 
    graph = nx.DiGraph(V)
    list(nx.all_simple_paths(graph, 0, 9001))
    Result: 4.83 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Timing from OP (see comments): this solution produces 12 Million paths in less than 20s, 
                               networkx takes in excess of 48s
```

**Modification to Avoid Cycles**

Although the current graph does not have cycles, a simple modification can be made to avoid them.

```
def dfs_stack_no_cycles(graph, start, goal):
    '''
        Depth First Search for all paths from start to goal
    '''
    graph = {k:set(v) for k, v in graph.items()}
    # Init stack to path with just starting vertex
    stack = [[start]]
    
    while stack:
        # Expand path at end of stack
        path = stack.pop()
        
        if path[-1] == goal:
            yield path                # reached goal
        else:
            # Add all paths of vertex to stack
            for start in graph[path[-1]] - set(path):
                stack.append(path + [start])
```

Comment: Thank you. Both functions work and runs quite fast.

Comment: @hcb -- great to hear.  I'm curious how this solution compares in timing to networkx on your larger datasets.

Comment: @DarryIG. Thank you. Great piece of code. I am currently building new graphs to test the above solutions on. That being said, your solution can produce 12Million paths in less than 20s, networkx takes in excess of 48s.